# compare keys of different Hashmaps

Tags: java

Let's say I have 2 Map's in Java. I want to compare map1's keys to map2's keys to see if there are any similar keys in the 2 maps.

How can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "smiler keys"?

Comment: that means if i map all the dates of month to key of the map using loop. And these dates has diferant values. and put that values as value of the map. now we hav another map that contain dates as keys and diffreant value as values. So i want to compare those 2 maps that has similer dates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the maps:

```
boolean thereAreCommonKeys = !Collections.disjoint(one.keySet(), two.keySet());
```

Finding the common keys:

```
Set<K> commonKeys = new HashSet<K>(one.keySet());
commonKeys.retainAll(two.keySet());
```

If your keys are dates, they should probably be something `Comparable`, in which case you might want a TreeSet instead of a HashSet, because it will keep them in order.

Comment: so then how can i print those smiler keys? it return boolean value

Comment: Well, you wanted to see if there are different keys ;)

Comment: He did, and that will teach me to take a questioner at his word. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ? If you want don't remove from m1 then you can do this **m3 = new(m1)**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Map<Integer, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

m1.put(1, 2);
m1.put(2, 3);

m2.put(1, 3);
m2.put(3, 4);

Map<Integer, Integer> m3 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(m1);  


Set s1 = m1.keySet();
Set s2 = m2.keySet();

System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s1.retainAll(s2));
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(m1);
System.out.println(m3);
```

Comment: Note that this will remove entries from m1!

Answer (score 1):

Map comparisons are made easier by [Maps.difference(..)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference%28java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map%29) method from Google's [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean hasOverlap = m1.keySet().retainAll(m2.keySet());
```

Comment: Note that this will remove entries from m1!

Comment: nope, this will remove entries from the keySet i got from m1, which isn't used anywhere else;

Comment: Wrong: if you remove elements from a keyset, *you remove the corresponding entries from the underlying map*. Check the javadoc.